# Spring Security modal login done right

Tags: spring-security

I know how to implement a spring security login form the "classical" way, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement a login form that opens in a modal and **always** behaves "properly".
It is not as trivial as it sounds.

Here are my specifications:

1. when an unauthenticated user requests a protected page, a modal login form should appear; when the login is successful, the requested page should appear and the address bar should display the requested url as in a non-modal approach

   1. when this is triggered from outside the site, the modal should open on the site home page
   2. when this is triggered from inside the site, the modal should open on the current page
2. when a user clicks on a "login" button on the site header (from any unprotected page) a modal login form should appear without changing page; when the login is successful, the location should not change but the page should be reloaded in order to be updated (e.g. showing the user name in the header)
3. if the modal is closed before submission, the original page should not have changed
4. if there are login errors, they should appear in the modal without redrawing the whole page
5. if the login form is submitted after session expiration, the login process should handle expired CSRF tokens gracefully (but I might consider removing them altogether for the login form, where I don't think are needed anyway)
6. every ajax request on the site (that originates from a protected page), should handle login requests gracefully
7. brute-force attacks should be hampered by temporarily suspending a username after some failed attempts
8. Java-only Spring configuration (no XML) and JQuery
9. the logout link should not trigger an authorization error when the session is expired

Comment: IMHO, the is way too broad for SO, with sub-questions about spring security configuration and others about javascript. Your preliminary analysis looks ok , so you could try to implement something and as more precise question if stuck.

Comment: I was hoping for people to contribute bits and pieces and eventually come up with the full solution that could become a reference for anyone. The reason why this is a monolithic question is that the answer for a single requisite might not satisfy another. I will post my findings later on.

Comment: That could be a nice idea. I could help on the spring security side, but I let you begin the javascript part (modal windows) - I can hardly read javascript, but not write :-( ... Feel free to call me through a comment as soon as you have written something.

Comment: For requisite 1.2 we need a way for Spring Security to redirect to the current page after adding a parameter that javascript could check to open the login modal, for example "/mycurrentpage?doLogin". I currently use http.formLogin().loginPage("/login") which always goes to the login page, breaking the requisite. But we also need the default behavior (going to a fixed page) for requisite 1.1

Comment: I've been thinking about what I wrote above and decided that probably Spring Security can't do anything about it because it can't know what the current page is (unless I send it as a request parameter, which is ugly). So now I think the solution is to have the login form opened from javascript when the user clicks on a navigation link that leads to a protected page. Haven't tried it though.

Comment: AFAIK, Spring security filters have a notion of *saved request* which is the request that caused the redirection because of insufficient access rights.